# Basic classes - Nested classes

Tags: c#, class

I have something like this:

```
public class Ship
{
    public void PositionX_pixels_set1(float _position_x){position_x = _position_x;}

    public class Engine : Ship
    {
        public int engines() { return 5; }
        public class Piston
        {
            public int pistons(){return 5;}
        }
    }

}


void Main
{
    Ship ship = new Ship()
    int a = ship.Engine.Piston.pistons;//why this not working?
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Why isn't "ship.Engine.Piston.pistons" working?

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?  Does it compile? Does it through an exception? Is an unexpected value calculated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Engine` is **type** inside the `Ship` class, and its **member**.

To fix this can do something like:

```
public class Ship
{
    public void PositionX_pixels_set1(float _position_x){position_x = _position_x;}

    private void Engine _myEngine = new Engine(); //DEFINE ENGINE MEMBER

    public Engine MyEngine {   //DEFINE A PROPERTY TO ACCESS THAT MEMBER
        get {
           return _myEngine;
        }
    }

    public class Engine : Ship
    {
        public int engines() { return 5; }
        private Piston _myPiston = new Piston();//DEFINE PISTON MEMBER

        public Piston MyPiston {//DEFINE A PROPERTY TO ACCESS THAT 
           get {
               return _myPiston ;
           }
        }

        public class Piston
        {
            public int pistons(){return 5;}
        }

       MEMBER
    }

}
```

and after use it like:

```
int a = ship.MyEngine.MyPiston.pistons
```

Answer (score 3):

You must initiate an object of your sub type (Nested type) in order to access its method, in your case you are not creating any object of your nested types so you can not access its methode.

While you create a `new Ship()` you are not creating any `Engine` or `Piston`, so you can not access the methode `Pistons()` of the non existing object.